# Where to pass " Instructions for merchant" while creating paypal order?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am looking for parameters that can be passed from the client-side in JS while creating the order in Paypal.

Here is sample code

```js
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
         "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100",
              "breakdown": {
                "item_total": {  /* Required when including the `items` array */
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100"
                }
              }
            },
            "items": getItemsArray()
      });
    },
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for specifically, but you can see a full sample of an items array within https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/ , and read the documentation for an orders create request at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed the link and related docs as well didn't find any details about parameters to pass instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the latest Paypal update, this feature has been removed.